# How to embed webkit into gtk+ program

Tags: c, webkit, gtk, dev-c++

I have downloaded webkitgtk+ , but cant figure out what i have to do next. My idea is to make a web browser. I use dev-c++ as IDE. I was first trying to do this with fltk but then i realised theres a port for gtk+ so i learnt gtk+.Pls. help

Comment: Have you any c/c++ programming experience ? Have you tried to follow a tutorial (e.g. [the one on live gnome](https://live.gnome.org/WebKitGtk/ProgrammingGuide)) ?

Comment: Yes i know c / c++ but not expertly.
Do i have to build webkitgtk+ from source?I'm on windows 7,not linux.

Comment: I don't know I'm not a windows expert but after googling a little bit it seems you will have to build the libraries from sources. Take care , there are two flavours of gtk porting (native mingw gcc and cygwin)